Find How Many Rectangles Contain Each Point
I have n delivery person details. A delivery person present at a point (x,y) can deliver to all points in a rectangle that has 4 corners (0,0), (x,0), (y,0), (x,y).
We do not have multiple delivery persons at same point.
Given a delivery point co-ordinate (a,b), find how many delivery persons available to deliver to this point.
Example:
Deliver person locations = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,5]]
Delivery points = [[1,1], [1,4]]

Result
[3,1]

Explanation:
Point [1,1] can be delivered by [1,2], [2,3], [1,5]
Point [1,4] can be delivered by [1,5]

Constraints:
number of locations and points range from 1 to 10^5
Delivery person location x and y range from 1 to 10^9
Deliver points location x is in range 1 to 10^9
Deliver points location y is in range 1 to 10^9

Here is my code:
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static List<Integer> solve(List<int[]> persons, List<int[]> locations) {
        List<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.sort((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p2[1], p1[1]));
        for (int[] r : locations) {
            int x = r[0];
            int y = r[1];
            int total = 0;
            for (int[] p : persons) {
                int x1 = p[0];
                int y1 = p[1];
                if (y1 < y) {
                    break;
                }
                if (x1 >= x && y1 >= y) {
                    total++;
                }
            }
            ar.add(total);
        }
        return ar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example usage
        List<int[]> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new int[]{1, 2});
        persons.add(new int[]{2, 3});
        persons.add(new int[]{1, 5});

        List<int[]> locations= new ArrayList<>();
        locations.add(new int[]{1, 1});
        locations.add(new int[]{1, 4});

        List<Integer> result = solve(persons, locations);
        System.out.println(result); // Output: [3, 1]
    }
}

If m is locations size and n is persons size, then my code complexity is n * log(n) + m*n
I want to reduce the time complexity of my code, what is the correct approach to solve this?

Questions about improving otherwise working code may be better suited for [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines and How to Ask to ensure an on-topic question.

You are only given one location, according to your question and title. So why does your code loop over locations? You can do this with a linear scan of the persons.

This seems like a trickier variant of the 1d problem where, given a fixed set of intervals and a list of query points on a number line, determine how many intervals contain each query point. Chances are an efficient solution to the easier problem may be extended to this one without too much effort.

@user207421 There can be up to 10^5 locations (from the "Constraints" section).

@jmoerdyk Algorithm questions are not off-topic here.

@Unmitigated I didn't say it was off-topic, just that it may be be better suited for Code Review. Just a comment, no down-vote or close vote from me.

@jmoerdyk Ah I see. In my experience, code review does not help much with algorithm questions as the answers focus too much on style over solving the problem efficiently.

This can be solved with line sweep. First, compress all the y coordinates to the range [0, 2 * 10^5 - 1]. Then, a binary indexed tree can be used to maintain the ranges that are not covered by each rectangle.
Time complexity: O((M + N) * log(M + N))
public static int[] solve(List<int[]> persons, List<int[]> locations) {
    class BIT {
        int[] bit;
        BIT(int n) {
            bit = new int[n];
        }
        void update(int i, int v) {
            for (; i < bit.length; i |= i + 1) bit[i] += v;
        }
        int query(int i) {
            int ret = 0;
            for (; i >= 0; i = (i & (i + 1)) - 1) ret += bit[i];
            return ret;
        }
    }
    record Event(int[] point, int queryIdx) {}
    var ys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    var evs = new ArrayList<Event>();
    for (var person : persons) {
        ys.add(person[1]);
        evs.add(new Event(person, -1));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
        var loc = locations.get(i);
        ys.add(loc[1]);
        evs.add(new Event(loc, i));
    }
    evs.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((Event ev) -> ev.point[0]).thenComparingInt(ev -> -ev.queryIdx));
    ys.sort(null);
    var bit = new BIT(ys.size());
    for (var person : persons) bit.update(Collections.binarySearch(ys, person[1]) + 1, 1);
    var ans = new int[locations.size()];
    for (var ev : evs)
        if (ev.queryIdx < 0) {
            bit.update(Collections.binarySearch(ys, ev.point[1]) + 1, -1);
            bit.update(0, 1);
        }
        else ans[ev.queryIdx] = persons.size() - bit.query(Collections.binarySearch(ys, ev.point[1]));
    return ans;
}

